# What is wrong with the following strcmp() code?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, strcmp, strcpy

I have a multidimensional array of a structure, whose content is initialized to '\0' initially and later occasionally. After some values are inserted, it is sorted on `fing_print` in an ascending order. Then the first n entries of the sorted array is copied into another array. In my implementation some of the array elements might not be assigned values, so they contain the '\0' values assigned to them earlier and they need to be ignored when copying into the other array.

My problem is, the code breaks at "**__DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_FUNC_0_1( errno_t, strcpy_s, _Post_z_ char, _Destination, _In_z_ char const*, _Source )**.

And upon debugging I have noticed that it breaks at the 
**`strcpy_s(selected[j][r].fing_print, hash_table[j][i].fing_print);`** line 
when **only one** of the **j (BUCKETS)** contains data.

```
for (int j = 0; j < BUCKETS; ++j) {
    // select rep fps here according to select size

    for (int i = 0,r=0; i<B_ENTRIES, r < SELECT_SIZE; ++i) {
        if (!strcmp(hash_table[j][i].fing_print, garb)) {
            // garb contains '\0'
            continue;
        }
        prev = i-1;
        if (!strcmp(hash_table[j]i].fing_print,
                    hash_table[j][prev].fing_print)) {
            // make sure the same fingerprint is not selected twice
            continue;
        }
        strcpy_s(selected[j][r].fing_print,
                 hash_table[j][i].fing_print);
        ++r;    
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015

Comment: Make sure it runs in C mode then!

Comment: Also see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx

Comment: Your `for` loop exit test is a comma expression that makes no sense.  Since there are no side effects in the first part, it serves no purpose.  I.e. `i<B_ENTRIES,r < SELECT_SIZE` is equivalent to `r < SELECT_SIZE`.  Please learn what the comma operator does before attempting to use it.

Comment: @alk I did as you said and I got thousands of errors from a code which compiled with no errors earlier. I hope you can tell me why.

Comment: @TomKarzes i am learning while making those mistakes and corrected by people like you. But I didn't mean that I have not read about it before I started on my project. You just can't learn everything the first time.

Comment: Strcpy_s has 3 parameters - destination, size and source.  You only have 2 so it is taking your source as the size and setting the source as 0.  Possibly the reason for your original crash

Comment: the question is a bout a run time problem.  However, only a small snippet of the code is posted.  How are we to debug without code the cleanly compiles, is short, and still exhibits the problem?  please post a [mcve]

Comment: `strcpy_s` in C library has **three** parameters. You are calling it with **two** arguments. Your code will not compile in a C compiler in Visual Studio. You are making something up.

Comment: @AnT that is correct. I have included that in my answer.

Comment: There's a templatized version of `strcpy_s` that deduces the size from the array being passed. Without seeing the appropriate declarations though it's hard to know if it's deducing the right value or not.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx

Comment: Note that `strcpy_s()` only needs two arguments when compiling C++ code if the first argument's type is an actual array (instead of a pointer). The library uses template type deduction to determine the size of the destination in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment section my mistake was in using the comma in the loop exit conditions `for (int i = 0,r=0; i<B_ENTRIES, r < SELECT_SIZE; ++i)` .correcting it to the following worked fine.

```
for (int j = 0; j < BUCKETS; ++j) {
    // select rep fps here according to select size
for (int i = 0,r=0; i<B_ENTRIES && r < SELECT_SIZE; ++i) {
    if (!strcmp(hash_table[j][i].fing_print, garb)) {
        // garb contains '\0'
        continue;
    }
    prev = i-1;
    if (!strcmp(hash_table[j]i].fing_print,
                hash_table[j][prev].fing_print)) {
        // make sure the same fingerprint is not selected twice
        continue;
    }
    strcpy_s(selected[j][r].fing_print,
             hash_table[j][i].fing_print);
    ++r;    
  }
}
```

The `strcpy_s()` function worked fine as it is, but again as pointed out in the comments above it missed one parameter which is the size of the destination array and so should be corrected to

```
strcpy_s(selected[j][r].fing_print,sizeof(selected[j][r].fing_print),
             hash_table[j][i].fing_print);
```